# Passing a parameter with quotes to a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, parameter

I have a useful script `greplog` that does:

```
grep -Eh --color $1 /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log{.1,}
```

so I can easily search like this:

```
greplog index.php
```

But

```
greplog "POST /test.php"
```

doesn't work: it searches for `POST` **or** `/test.php` whereas it should be a full pattern search, with the space included. Why?

Why isn't `$1` replaced by `"POST /test.php"`? Indeed this works fine:

```
grep -Eh --color "POST /test.php" /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log{.1,}
```

Comment: `$1` is replaced by `POST /test.php`, not `"POST /test.php"` - wrap your parameter in quotes: `"$1"`

Comment: Thanks, you can post this as an answer @Panki!

Comment: No problem - it's already a dupe though, so theres no need to write another answer :)